# How do I remove an Exchange 2010 server from the domain

Tags: exchange-2010

We have recently migrated all email for our organization to Office 365 from an Exchange 2010 on-premises server. It was a single Exchange server that had been migrated from a Exchange 2003 server some time. I have encountered two issues that is keeping Exchange 2010 from uninstalling. One issue is that the Database cannot be removed because the

> "mailbox database contains one or more mailboxes, mailbox plans,
>   archive mailboxes, or arbitration mailboxes"

even though I have deleted all of the mailboxes.

The second issue is that

> "Public folder database "Public Folder Database 0419058239" is the
>   default public folder database for the following mailbox database(s):
>   Mailbox Database 1609800457 . Before deleting the public folder
>   database, assign a new default public folder database to the mailbox
>   database(s)."

Another error that comes up is

> This computer is configured as a bridgehead server for 2 routing group
>   connector(s) in the organization. These must be moved or deleted
>   before Setup can continue. I would like to repurpose the hardware
>   which includes reformatting and installing a different os but I am
>   afraid that these issue will continue manifest as different problems
>   in the domain if I do not properly uninstall the Exchange 2010.

Attempts to force removal comes up with error messages that imply that the Offline Address Book has to be moved before the Exchange can be removed. Is the OAB really necessary if all Exchange stuff is in the cloud? Is the OAB necessary for other Active Directory functions in the domain?

There are number of things going on. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Before giving you a full answer, let me ask the following 1) is this the last exchange server in the organization? 2) is DirSync or SSO are being used with Office 365? 3) Is "force" removing exchange an option?

Comment: @Noor. Yes, it is the last exchange server in the organization. We are using neither DirSync nor Sso.  Force is an option if that will not leave an "orphan" exchange instance on the domain. Thank you for your help.